# Repeat the rows in table application on angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a table application

The event on button "Добавить" add new rows in my tablle ->

```
addRowMainForm(){
        this.rowDataMainForm.push({
            nomer: '',
            tip_podr: '',
            tip_ray: '',
            tocki_starta: '',
            del: '',
        })
    }

addRowTochkiStartaForm(){
    this.rowDataTochkiStartaForm.push({
        nomer_t_s: '',
        vel_x: '',
        vel_y: '',
        height: '',
        geometry: '',
        rockets: '',
        delete: '',
    })
}

addRowRocketForm(){
    this.rowDataRocketForm.push({
        tip_r: '',
        tip_gch: '',
        kol: '',
        delete: '',
    })
}
```

I have a problem with new rows, they are repeated. If i add a two or more new rows for ex. in addRowMainForm(), they added in addRowTochkiStartaForm() to.

[add row in addRowTochkiStartaForm()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VizhE.png)

[and then i add a new row in addRowMainForm(), those three rows addRowTochkiStartaForm() repeated in addRowMainForm()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOVlU.png)

This is html template ->

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Подразделение
            </h4>
        </div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Номер</th>
    <th>Тип подразделения</th>
    <th>Тип района</th>
    <th>Точки старта</th>
    <th>Удалить</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let row of rowDataMainForm; let mainFormIndex = index">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected>-----</option>
            <option value="Д">Д</option>
            <option value="Б">Б</option>
            <option value="П">П</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
         <select class="form-control">
            <option selected>-----</option>
            <option value="Основной">Основной</option>
            <option value="Запасной">Запасной</option>
            <option value="Временный">Временный</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="panel panel-default smaller">    
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>номер</th>
                <th>радиус</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
                <th>Высота</th>
                <th>Геометрия</th>
                <th>Ракеты</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr *ngFor="let newrow of rowDataTochkiStartaForm; let TochkiStartaFormIndex = index">
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                     <div class="panel panel-default smaller">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Тип</th>
                                    <th>Тип ГЧ</th>
                                    <th>Кол-во</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let suchnewrow of rowDataRocketForm; let RocketFormIndex = index">
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button (click)="deleteRowRocketForm(RocketFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px;">
                                        Удалить
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="container-build">
                                <button (click)='addRowRocketForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                                    Добавить
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)='deleteRowTochkiStartaForm(TochkiStartaFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                        Удалить
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="container-build">
                <button (click)='addRowTochkiStartaForm()' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                    Добавить
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button (click)="deleteDataMainForm(mainFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
            Удалить
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="container-build">
        <button (click)='addRowMainForm(mainFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
            Добавить
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is a property of my component

```
 rowDataMainForm = [{
    nomer: '',
    tip_podr: '',
    tip_ray: '',
    tocki_starta: '',
    del: '',
}];

rowDataTochkiStartaForm = [{
    nomer_t_s: '',
    vel_x: '',
    vel_y: '',
    height: '',
    geometry: '',
    rockets: '',
    delete: '',
}];

rowDataRocketForm = [{
    tip_r: '',
    tip_gch: '',
    kol: '',
    delete: '',
}];
```

Please, help me, what i can do to the rows are not repeated?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why do you do not use ng-repeat and add the data row into the variable that control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new file called `forms.class.ts` and insert this code:

```js
export class MainForm {
    nomer: string = '';
    tip_podr: string = '';
    tip_ray: string = '';
    tocki_starta: string = '';
    del: boolean = false;

    tochkiStartaForms: Array<TochkiStartaForm> = [ new TochkiStartaForm() ];
}

export class TochkiStartaForm {
    nomer_t_s: string = '';
    vel_x: number = 0;
    vel_y: number = 0;
    geometry: string = '';
    rockets: string = '';
    delete: boolean = false;

    rocketForms: Array<RocketForm> = [ new RocketForm() ];
}

export class RocketForm {
    tip_r: string = '';
    tip_gch: string = '';
    kol: string = '';
    delete: boolean = false;
}
```

You only need one variable in your component now like this:

```
rowDataMainForm: Array<MainForm> = [ new MainForm() ];
```

And in the HTML refer to the child arrays in the `*ngFor` and in the `(click)='add...` events:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Подразделение
            </h4>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Номер</th>
                <th>Тип подразделения</th>
                <th>Тип района</th>
                <th>Точки старта</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of rowDataMainForm; let mainFormIndex = index">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option selected>-----</option>
                        <option value="Д">Д</option>
                        <option value="Б">Б</option>
                        <option value="П">П</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option selected>-----</option>
                        <option value="Основной">Основной</option>
                        <option value="Запасной">Запасной</option>
                        <option value="Временный">Временный</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="panel panel-default smaller">
                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>номер</th>
                                    <th>радиус</th>
                                    <th>X</th>
                                    <th>Y</th>
                                    <th>Высота</th>
                                    <th>Геометрия</th>
                                    <th>Ракеты</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let newrow of row.tochkiStartaForms; let TochkiStartaFormIndex = index">
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="panel panel-default smaller">
                                        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Тип</th>
                                                    <th>Тип ГЧ</th>
                                                    <th>Кол-во</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tr *ngFor="let suchnewrow of newrow.rocketForms; let RocketFormIndex = index">
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button (click)="deleteRowRocketForm(newrow.rocketForms, RocketFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px;">
                                                        Удалить
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="panel-footer">
                                            <div class="container-build">
                                                <button (click)='addRowRocketForm(newrow.rocketForms)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                                                    Добавить
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button (click)='deleteRowTochkiStartaForm(row.tochkiStartaForms, TochkiStartaFormIndex)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                                        Удалить
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="container-build">
                                <button (click)='addRowTochkiStartaForm(row.tochkiStartaForms)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                                    Добавить
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button (click)="deleteDataMainForm(rowDataMainForm, mainFormIndex)" type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                        Удалить
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="container-build">
                <button (click)='addRowMainForm(rowDataMainForm)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">
                    Добавить
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your add methods need to refer to the passed array:

```js
addRowMainForm(arr: Array<any>) {
    arr.push(new MainForm());
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

addRowTochkiStartaForm(arr: Array<any>){
    arr.push(new TochkiStartaForm());
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

addRowRocketForm(arr: Array<any>){
    arr.push(new RocketForm());
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

And in your delete methods:

```
deleteRowMainForm(arr: Array<any>, rowNumber: number){
    arr.splice(rowNumber, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

deleteRowTochkiStartaForm(arr: Array<any>, rowNumber: number){
    arr.splice(rowNumber, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

deleteRowRocketForm(arr: Array<any>, rowNumber: number){
    arr.splice(rowNumber, 1);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: i cant encapsulate that code - > rowDataMainForm = [{ ... }] - > visual code give me this error -> connot find name rowDataTochkiStartaForm

Comment: What exactly do you mean with that?

Comment: i cant encapsulate that code - > rowDataMainForm = [{ ... }] - > visual code give me this error -> connot find name rowDataTochkiStartaForm

Comment: do you know, what is the problem?

Comment: I completely reworked my answer - please check it out!

Comment: and what i import on form.class.ts?

Comment: `import {MainForm, TochkiStartaForm, RocketForm} from 'form.class';`

Comment: and now i have this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: When you do what? On which line?

Comment: when i click the second button "Добавить" - > i`ve got this error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Ah yes, a typo - it should read `<button (click)='addRowTochkiStartaForm(row.tochkiStartaForms)' type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="padding: 2px">` ... I wrote `Form` instead of `Forms`

Comment: and now when i click over right button "Удалить", i have this error -> TypeError: self.parent.context.deleteDataMainForm is not a function

Comment: Yes, I don't know the namings of your delete methods, it was just to visualize how it **should** look like. Please try and fix that yourself - you just have to change the names of your delete methods or the calls in your template.

Comment: ow, this is my fail ) THANK YOU !!

Comment: can you tell me pls, how i can hide i firts row in my table, and add event on hide in button "Добавить"?

Comment: Please open a new question for that.

Comment: Well, you should use a combination of `[hidden]='expression'` and `(click)=''`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125986/how-hide-element-of-table-by-hidden-in-angular-2 this que.

Comment: i add this code for hide and show table -> `toggleElement(arr: Array<any>){
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        if(this.hideElement){
            this.hideElement = false;
        } else {
            this.hideElement = true;
        }
    }` and now i have a same trouble with repead every table, if i hide 1 element, hide 3 or more elements